# What is this object serialization pattern?

Tags: serialization

Have you ever taken a close look at some of the urls produced as you browse around www.amazon.com? Here's a typical one:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_age_range_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abumblebee%2Cp_n_age_range%3A165890011%7C165936011&keywords=bumblebee&ie=UTF8&qid=1373589657&rnid=165794011
```

After you urldecode it, you get:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_89_2?rh=i:aps,k:bumblebee,p_n_age_range:165890011|165936011,p_89:Pillow Pets&keywords=bumblebee&ie=UTF8&qid=1373589678&rnid=2528832011
```

I'm particularly interested in this portion:

> rh=i:aps,k:bumblebee,p_n_age_range:165890011|165936011,p_89:Pillow Pets

It looks like some kind of object serialization that reduces down even smaller than JSON. There are no quotes around strings, and arrays are bracketless and delimited by pipes.

Ebay does something similar, particularly the array pipes. Have you ever seen this format? Is this a common pattern you recognize? Or is it just some exotic hand-rolled solution that they both happened to arrive at independently? Any idea why they do it, as opposed to just straight JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, John--for the life of me I couldn't get the code tags to work